# Vue component not updating on state change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

```
<div v-for="(photon, key) in $store.state.notConnected" v-bind:key="key">
    <div v-if="!photon.connected">
        <p>Photon is not Connected</p>
    </div>
    <div v-if="photon.connected">
        <p>Photon is Connected</p>
        <b-btn v-on:click="showNewSetup(photon)>Setup</b-btn>
    </div>
    <div v-if="photon.showSetup">Setup Page</div>
</div>
```

Store.js

```
export const store = new Vuex.store({
 state:{
   notConnected:{}
 },
 mutations:{
 setDevices(state,value){
 value.data.forEach(ele =>{
 state.notConnected[ele.id]={}
 state.notConnected[ele.id].showSetup=false
 state.notConnected[ele.id].connected=ele.connected
 }
 },
 SHOWNEWSETUP(state,value){
  state.notConnected[value.id].showSetup=true
}}
actions:{
async getDevices(context){
let devices = await axios.get('http:10.10.10.1:3000/api')
context.commit('setDevices',devices)
}
}
})
```

I'm mutating the state in my vuex store but the v-if doesn't reflect the updated state. When I open up vue dev tools I see the mutation happen and can see that the state has changed, but the setup page div isn't updating.

Note: If i go to a diffrent route and go back to the page the component updates

Comment: Can you show more code; what does your initial state looks like ?

Comment: you're missing a double quote after .notConnected

Comment: @gugateider That was just a typo on this example

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `photon.id` as the key?

Comment: @JamesCoyle I could use that but it doesn't make a difference, vue just needs a unique way to track the components

Comment: Try using mapState instead of accessing it directly

Answer (score 1):

Vue has no chance to detect changes in Arrays (except vue3 with proxy support).

That's why you should alter your mutation to:

```
SHOWNEWSETUP(state,value){
  Vue.set(state.notConnected, value.id, {showSetup=true})
}
```

That way Vue's reactivity system is informed about the change and everything should work as expected.

Comment: That changed the state, but the component still wasn't updating

Comment: So I ended up having to delete the object and recreating it. `SHOWNEWSETUP(state,value){                                                                       delete state.notConnected[value.id]                                                       value.showSetup=true                                                                                               Vue.set(state.notConnected,value.id,value)}`

Answer (score 1):

Try using a computed property in your component instead of pointing to state directly:

```
<template>
    <div v-for="(photon, key) in photons v-bind:key="key">
        <div v-if="!photon.connected">
            <p>Photon is not Connected</p>
    </div>
    <div v-if="photon.connected">
        <p>Photon is Connected</p>
        <b-btn v-on:click="showNewSetup(photon)>Setup</b-btn>
    </div>
        <div v-if="photon.showSetup">Setup Page</div>
    </div>   
</template>

<script>
    computed: {
        photons() {
            return this.$store.state.notConnected
        },
    }
</script>
```

Comment: That didn't work :( everything is still behaving the same